# Serializable class not found CLASSNAME error is thrown when moving class package(even thought serialVersionUID is stated in class)

Tags: java, redis, serializable, redisson, serialversionuid

I am working with Redis(via redisson) I have a DTO class that I am serializing an deserializing into Redis,

the codec I am using is:

org.redisson.codec.FstCodec

when I move the class to a diffrent namespace despite setting the: serialVersionUID explicitly in the DTO class in class I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class not found CLASSNAME:db.data.coins.CoinDTO loader:jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6ed3ef1
```

In the example I moved the class from package:

db.data.coins.CoinDTO

to package:

dto

Link to fstCodec github:

[link](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization)

```
package dto; // altering package

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class CoinDTO implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private double amount;

    private Timestamp timestamp;

   //Getters and setters

}
```

I would like to alter the package and still get the class from Redis.

Many thanks in advance

P.S

The way I am currently handling it is by serializing of the object using json and then setting it into redis, but that is just double serialization and I would like to avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I move the class to a diffrent namespace despite setting the: serialVersionUID explicitly in the DTO class in class I get the following exception:

You can't deserialize object if its package or class name has changed.

> The way I am currently handling it is by serializing of the object using json and then setting it into redis

You could set Redisson to Jackson as follow `codec = org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec`